# How can I pass information from child component to parent in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

With React I'm trying to pass data from a child component into the parent component. So I'd like the user to be able to input data into the text fields (one in data1 and one in data2) in the child component and place them into the data set in the parent component.

I tried a test function just to log the state from the parent component to confirm it had passed along correctly but my console log reads test detects [object Object] and [object Object] and I can't figure out why.

How can I pass information into data in the parent component?

### PARENT COMPONENT

```
function Main() {

    const [data, setData] = useState({
      data1:'',
      data2:'',
      data3:'',
      data4:'',
    })


return(
   <div>
   Always here Content
   </div>

    <ChildComponent
      data={data}
      setData={setData}
    />
)}
```

### Child Component

```
function childComponent({ data, setData }){

      const test = () => {
        console.log('test detects ' + {data} + ' and ' + {setData})
      }

    return(

        <div>
        Some Rotating Content
        </div>

        <div>
        <TextField 
            id="outline-basic" 
            label="data1"
            name="data1"
            value={data1}
          />

        <TextField 
            id="outline-basic" 
            label="data2"
            name="data2"
            value={data2}
          />

        </div>
       <button onClick={() => {test()}}>Submit</button>


    )
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use `value={data.data1}` because `{data1}` has no meaning, you want the value to be equal to the value of the property `data1` of `data`

you want to update the parent state when you make a change with the input, depending on `e.target.name` **which should be equal to the name of the property in your state object** and take advantage also of `e.target.value` we update the parent state.
here `{ ...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value }` we return a copy of `prev` but with the property "[e.target.name]" equal to `e.target.value`.
what we return is its new value of the state and and `prev` is its current value

with each update, you are rendering the two components, updating the state in the parent one, then passing it to the child, so when you console log it from the child you will always see the updated data, in fact, it is easier to see it from inputs values shown on the screen, those values are received from the parent state after each update.

```js
import { useState } from "react";

const Main = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    data1: "",
    data2: "",
    data3: "",
    data4: "",
  });

  return <ChildComponent data={data} setData={setData} />;
};

export default Main;

// make sure it starts with Capital letter
const ChildComponent = ({ data, setData }) => {
  const test = () => {
    console.log("test detects ", data);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <input
        id="outline-basic"
        label="data1"
        name="data1"
        value={data.data1}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setData((prev) => {
            return { ...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value };
          });
        }}
      />
      <input
        id="outline-basic"
        label="data2"
        name="data2"
        value={data.data2}
        onChange={(e) => {
          setData((prev) => {
            return { ...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value };
          });
        }}
      />

      <button
        onClick={() => {
          test();
        }}
      >
        Submit
      </button>
    </>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 0):

**First** you cannot log the `data` and `setData` together in the Child because, `data` is empty since you have not initialized it and `setData` is a function to initialize or assign value to the `data`.

**Second** you cannot access the `data1` directly since it is inside the `data` object. You need to use `data.data1` to access it.

**Then** Try to `log` the data in the `Main` Component since you want the data to be in that(parent)

```
export function Main() {
  const [data, setData] = useState({
    data1: "",
    data2: "",
    data3: "",
    data4: ""
  });

  console.log(data);

  return <ChildComponent data={data} setData={setData} />;
}
```

In the `ChildComponent` you need to make the text fields as **Controlled Inputs** so that the State is updated whenever the input fields are modified

```
export function ChildComponent({ data, setData }) {

  return (
    <div>
      <input
        type="text"
        id="outline-basic"
        label="data1"
        name="data1"
        value={data.data1}
        onChange={(e) => setData({ ...data, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })}
      />

      <input
        type="text"
        id="outline-basic"
        label="data2"
        name="data2"
        value={data.data2}
        onChange={(e) => setData({ ...data, [e.target.name]: e.target.value })}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Now** you will be able to see the Console Log in the Parent whenever you type something in the Text Fields in the Child component.

Comment: u are free to do whatever u want but I want to know what's the point of copying an existing answer

Comment: @Hatana What made you think the answer was copied? Your accusation don't have a basis

Comment: I don't mean it is copied but the same idea is already posted